# Loop through elements and change the classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is a simple HTML code:

```html
<div class="rowIdeas">

  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img src="icons/philosophy.svg">
    <h2>title 1</h2>
    <p>some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>

  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img src="icons/english.svg">
    <h2>title 1</h2>
    <p>some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>

  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img src="icons/math.svg">
    <h2>title 1</h2>
    <p>some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to add 3 different classes to the elements dynamically using Javascript or jQuery like this:

```
<div class="rowIdeas">

  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img class="classA" src="icons/english.svg">
    <h2 class="classB">title 1</h2>
    <p class="classC">some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>

  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img class="classA" src="icons/english.svg">
    <h2 class="classB">title 1</h2>
    <p class="classC">some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>

  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img class="classA" src="icons/english.svg">
    <h2 class="classB">title 1</h2>
    <p class="classC">some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can we achieve this?

I know how to change a class using javascript but it's hard to understand how to loop through elements and find the right element and add the class into it. Please help...

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/), [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to loop through elements and find the right element and add the class into it

assuming you don't want to just do

```
$(".columnIdeas>img").addClass("classA");
$(".columnIdeas>h2").addClass("classB");
$(".columnIdeas>p").addClass("classC");
```

which doesn't require any looping or "finding", you can add the classes "automatically" using `.each` and `.find`:

```js
var classList = ["classA", "classB", "classC"];

$(".columnIdeas").each((i, e) => {
  $(e).find(">*").each((ii, ee) =>{
    $(ee).addClass(classList[ii]);
  });
});
```

```css
.classA {
  color: red;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.classB {
  color: blue;
}

.classC {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rowIdeas">
  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img src="icons/philosophy.svg">
    <h2>title 1</h2>
    <p>some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>
  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img src="icons/english.svg">
    <h2>title 1</h2>
    <p>some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>
  <div class="columnIdeas">
    <img src="icons/math.svg">
    <h2>title 1</h2>
    <p>some text <span style="color: #9052fa"> goes</span> here </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you used class1/class2 etc, you could replace `classList` with `"class" + (ii+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.columnIdeas').each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).find('img').addClass('classA');
  $(el).find('h2').addClass('classB');
  $(el).find('p').addClass('classC');
});
```